# Time varying coefficients with splines in Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model, splines, time-varying-covariate

I am wondering whether it is valid to fit spline interactions between time and predictor variables (either categorical or continuous) in a Cox model. I am having difficulties specifying this model, which makes me think that it might not be appropriate. Here is my attempt so far (R code below), which produces estimates (Hazard ratios), though I don't think it is quite right. If such an approach is possible, I would be really grateful some advice on how to do it correctly!

```r
library(survival)
library(rms)

# attempt to interact categorical predictor (cell type) with a 
# restricted cubic spline (rcs) of time
f1 <- coxph(
  Surv(time, status) ~ celltype + tt(celltype),
  data = veteran,
  tt =function(celltype, t, ...) {
    model.matrix( ~ celltype)[, -1] * rcs(t, 4)
  }
)

# attempt to add an interaction between rcs(karno) * rcs(time)
f2 <-  coxph(
    Surv(time, status) ~ celltype + tt(celltype) + rcs(karno, 4) + 
    tt(karno),
    data = veteran,
    tt =list( function(celltype, t, ...) {
      model.matrix( ~ celltype)[, -1] * rcs(t, 4)
    },
    function(karno, t, ...) {
      rcs(karno,4) * rcs(t, 4)
    })
  )
```